# How do I describe the (N-X) column in a table with N columns?

Tags: numbers

Say I have a table like this:

```
|---------------------------|
|C1|C2|.....|C10|C11|C12|C13|
|---------------------------|
```

How do I describe the column C10?

The fourth from the last?

The fourth from the bottom?

The last but fourth?

Is there any rules about it?

Thanks

Comment: These are columns, not rows, so it wouldn't be "fourth from the bottom".

Comment: fourth from the right? fourth from the last?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We go left to right with respect to columns (and from top to bottom with rows). So in English we would say the tenth column; in standard math notation, it would be c_{10}, where the _{10} is a subscript.

It is also standard in math to specify row before column. So the cell specified by x_{3, 8} would be the cell in the third row **FROM THE TOP** and the eighth column **FROM THE LEFT**.

This is a simple translation problem between the language of mathematics and English.

Comment: Thanks! but what if the table is very huge and sometimes with an unsure columns that I have to describe it from the right?

Comment: Then just say “the xth column counting from the right.”